# No DOM Explorer or JS Console in Visual Studio 2017 - Debugging Office Add-In Excel

Tags: excel, debugging, visual-studio-2017, office-js

I can't figure out how to get the DOM Explorer or JS Console to show on my Office Add-In I'm dev in VS 2017. They used to work and one day, just stopped.

So far I've tried the following:

- Test Proj at home and copied source files to non working work computer
- Removed 100% Visual Studio and re-installed
- Started working w/ new template in VS 2017 vs my existing Project
- Tried messing w/ .Net versions
- Updated all available Nuget packages
- Other settings too likely, I'm willing to start fresh if anyone has suggestions that don't work first try for me.

I'm at a loss what the issue could be. My Add-Ins load and behave correctly, but I can't see the DOM or JS console which is the whole reason I use VS 2017, any ideas what I can try?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve by uninstalling the `Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime`...

Comment: After a lot of my life wasted I might add :(....

Comment: You can also debug using the Edge Chromium tools while using more recent versions of Visual Studio. See https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/debug-office-add-ins-in-visual-studio#debug-the-excel-powerpoint-or-word-add-in

Comment: @RickKirkham I understand that JS Console was removed in recent versions of VS. VS 2017 works great for what I need, I love the DOM Explorer and the Tree explorer for whats loaded. I'm able to manipulate the DOM and see CSS changes live. My question is did I install Edge WebView 2 runtime or was that an "update". I wonder if many ppl will have the same issue I had if its an update. I did resetup Windows recently, but it worked at first and at some point it broke. I feel like I'd have put two and two together if I installed Webview runtime that it broke VS, but possible I didn't put it together